# How can I make a CSS only popup or tooltip?

Tags: html, css

I've made some code for making a paragraph scrollable. I want to make all of the content outside of the popup `<div>` invisible. Can I do it with only HTML and CSS?

```html
<div style="position:relative;">
  <div id="popup" style=" overflow: hidden;  position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px;">This must be visible. And everything out of this div, must be hidden</div>

  <div style="position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-50px;">the tooltip thing</div>
</div>

<p>These must be hidden.</p>
<p>These must be hidden.</p>
<p> And These too</p>
```

Here is the pop-up code(noscript):

```
<style>
div.po
   {
   display: none;
   } 
div.p
   {
   display: block;
   } 

button:hover + div.p {
    display: none;
    }
button:hover + div.po {
    display:block;
    }
</style>
<button>Show</button>

<div class="p">Other contents</div>
<div class="po">Popup</div>
```

css button: hover is only changing one elements style.
when button is pressed, I want to make both 'div.po - style' into display: block
 and 'div.p - style' into display: none.

Comment: I'm trying to make a simple popup with only html and css. When a button get hovered, the div.popup's display changes into block.

Comment: If you don't use inline CSS you can assign the hidden items a class with `"display: none"` or make all children of the parent class hidden and add a special case below for popup.

Comment: I'm using this code for changing display property of div.popup:<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#popup {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
}
    
#button:hover + #popup {
    display: block;
}

#popup:hover {
    display: block;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url(../popup/bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
font-size:3em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="button">Pop-up</div>
<br>
<div style="position:relative;"> <div id="popup" style="overflow:visible; position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px;">the main content</div>

Comment: Can you add your above comment code to the question as code?

Comment: @fjoe yeah, I've added it.

Comment: Don't do this. Hover effects are inaccessible to keyboard-only users.

Comment: @zzzzBov not a problem. This question is only for my school work. Our work is, to make an awesome website with only using HTML and CSS. I've made a drop down menu for that. Next step is a pop-up

Comment: @zzzzBov but still your information is worth for me. Because, I was going to my drop down menu for my own website. Now I'll cancel that operation.

Comment: But still need to complete my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:
    Body text.

```
</div>
<div id="popup">
<a href="index.html">
Close
</a>
This is pop-up text
</div>
</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#popup_bg
  {
   display:none;
   height:100vh;
   width:100vh;
   position: fixed;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   }
#popup_bg
  {
   display:none;
   height:10vh;
   width:10vh;
   position: fixed;
   left:45%;
   right:45%;
   }
#box: checked
#popup_bg
  {
   display:block;
   }
#box: checked
#popup
  {
   display:block;
   }
```

It's been a long time, since I asked this this question.
But there was no right answer.
But now I know everything I want. Here is the code.

Answer (score 2):

**The most important part of this is the edit section. Read it.**

If you don't use inline CSS you can assign the hidden items a class with `display: none` or make all children of the parent class hidden and add a special case below for popup. Make all items in the parent hidden by default. Remember, CSS is *Cascading* Style Sheets, so popup takes priority.

```
.parent * {
    display: none;
}

.parent popup {
    display: initial;
    /* Or if you want block, like you said in your comment: */
    display: block;
}
```

But if it was already a block initial will work fine.

**Edit:** Based on the comments below (you should read them, they contribute a lot to this) this is what I have made.

```css
.tooltip-content {
  display: none;
}

.show-tooltip:hover + .tooltip-content {
  display: block;
}

.show-tooltip:hover ~ * {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="tooltip-section">
  <button class="show-tooltip">Show Tooltip</button>
  <p class="tooltip-content">Tooltip Content</p>
  <p>Other Content</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is the same thing, but in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spikespaz/9xakcd8c/).

Basically, it's hiding the `tooltip-content` class by default. When the sibling `show-tooltip` button is hovered, it hides all unassigned siblings and shows the *adjacent* `tooltip-content` sibling. This doesn't have to be paragraphs, but this should get you started with what you need.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

From what I read in your post and comments it looks like you are trying to get a specific paragraph to act like a popup by making that paragraph scroll-able while also hiding everything thing else on the page.

It also looks like you are using [in-line](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-css-inline-style-3466446) styling as opposed to using a CSS StyleSheet. I also don't see any mention of JavaScript either.

**Answer:**

So, to answer your question on if you can do all that with just HTML and CSS, I believe the answer is no, since you cannot dynamically affect one html element directly from another html element. You may be able to use inheritance as a tricky workaround, but if you got it to work it would most likely be messy and doesn't have much of a place in modern web development.

You also mentioned "hover" in one of your comments so you may be familiar with Psudeo-selectors, but you cannot use Psudeo-Selectors with inline styling. In addition, Psudeo-selectors will change the displayed html of a specific element and possibly it's children, but not all the elements on the page, unless that specific element happens to be the top-level element.

To give you a solution though, I would suggest using HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript to do what's called "Burn and Re-build." It's a common structure found in [Single-Page Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) where a user might navigate through different pages on the website, but in reality the content is all being hidden, then only specific sections are shown.

There are many ways to do this, but most people will use JavaScript EventListeners at first, and as they get more experienced they will learn to use other tools like jQuery, or Angular/React to update the html page (aka the DOM ). Any of those suggestions will give you the tools you need to achieve your goal, but I don't think it is possible in pure HTML w/inline styling.

***Solution***:

One of the ways to get what you want would be to use HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript EventListeners. First you need to write 2 different styling classes in your CSS: '.show' and .'hide' .

```
.show {
   visibility:visible;
}
.hide {
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

- Note that I used visibility instead of display. This is because display is used for layout and flow, whereas visibility handles if an element can be seen or not. Also, if you use something like display:initial; or display:block; you will mess up any formatting that your other classes had, and it will break tables and lists. When you apply one of these classes to one of your HTML tags, it will either hide or show that tag along with all of it's children as well.
- Also note that you actually do not need to change the class to .show, you just need to remove the .hide class and the element will revert back to it's default visibility. In my experience it is better to use .hide *and* .show because it' more imperative. In addition, I may want to change something about an element that was previously hidden differently than I would an element that has neither been hidden nor shown. I still recommend using visibility instead of display since you may still mess up your positioning if you use display.

Next, you need to write a function that will be called anytime a user clicks on your button. When a user clicks the button, your function will need to do a couple things:

- Get a collection of all elements you are going to either hide or show.
- Go through that collection and hide/show the correct elements appropriately.

Once you have the function written then you need to attach an EventListener to your button that will call this function each time the button is clicked!

Here is the code that I wrote and tested for you. I hope it helps!

**JavaScript, CSS, and HTML5 code:**

```js
/* Commented code is running on the bottom. This is the un commented version for easier reading.

'use strict'

let hidden = false

let showPopup = function(){ 
 
  let main = document.getElementById('main').children
  
  if (!hidden){ 
    for(let i=0; i< main.length; i++){
      if(main[i].id !== "popup"){
       main[i].classList.remove('show')
       main[i].classList.add('hide')
       
      }else{
        main[i].classList.add('popup-para') 
      }
    }

    hidden = !hidden 
 
  }else{ 
    for(let i=0; i< main.length; i++){
      main[i].classList.remove('hide')
      main[i].classList.remove('popup-para')
      main[i].classList.add('show')
    }
    
    hidden = !hidden
  }
  
 console.log( document.getElementById('test-para').classList )
}

document.getElementById('popup-button').onclick = showPopup

*/


'use strict'

// Tracks if the popup is active or not. 
let hidden = false

// This is the function that will be called each time the user clicks on your button.
let showPopup = function() {

  // Finds the "main" tag by it's id and then gets all of it's child elements
  // Then stores those child elements into an array called main.
  let main = document.getElementById('main').children

  if (!hidden) { // If not hidden, hide everything and show popup.

    for (let i = 0; i < main.length; i++) {

      // This part loops over each child element and checks it's id.
      // If it's id does not equal "popup" then hide it.

      if (main[i].id !== "popup") {

        main[i].classList.remove('show')
        main[i].classList.add('hide')

      } else {
        main[i].classList.add('popup-para') // Will give the specific popup the popup class.
      }
    }

    // This could also be written as hidden = true.
    // This allows the function to move to the else block the next time it's called.
    hidden = !hidden

  } else { // This is the opposite of the above if statement. It will un-hide everything and remove the popup class.

    for (let i = 0; i < main.length; i++) {

      main[i].classList.remove('hide')
      main[i].classList.remove('popup-para')
      main[i].classList.add('show')
    }

    hidden = !hidden // Sets hidden = false
  }

  // This is to show the other classes are not accidentally overwritten.
  // Checkout number 3 in the console.
  console.log(document.getElementById('test-para').classList)
}

// This tells the event what function to call when the event is triggered. 
// This has to be written below the function it is calling due to 'hoisting'.
document.getElementById('popup-button').onclick = showPopup
```

```css
.show {
  visibility: visible;
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.class-1 {
  color: purple;
}

.c1 {
  height: 10%;
  width: 60%;
}

.popup-para {
  max-height: 10em;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 32px;
  overflow: scroll;
  color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <main id="main">
    <h1> This is the main page content </h1>
    <ol>
      <li> Here's a list item. </li>
      <li> Here's anotha! </li>
    </ol>
    <p> Your button is just after this paragraph </p>
    <div id="popup">
      <button id="popup-button" class="c1 c2 c3 c4">Click to hide or show all other sections</button>
      <p> This is the paragarah that you want to look like it has popped up. I also have it changing it's text color let it stand out more! Also notice that it has kept the same position on the page and didn't jump up to the top. This is because we changed
        the visibility of all the other elements as opposed to the display! They still maintain their positioning and flow!

        <p> This paragrah shows up too because it is inside the popup div! Trying to fill space here, too lazy to get the Ipsum. Let's breakdown the JavaScript document object a bit. When we say document.getElementById('main') we are saying, "Hey, go look
          at the entire HTML5 file, document, and get me each element that has an id of 'main', .getElementById('main'), then store those children into the variable 'main' as an array!" Since each id is unique, there can only be one thing that is returned
          when we call .getElementById(). If you happen to have two elements in your HTML that have the same id, then only the first one will get returned. What is returned is actually called an Element object. Since it is an object, it also has properties!
          One of those properties is called children and since an element can possibly have multiple children, it will return an array! Each item in that array is another Element object that references that specific element in the HTML file! Should have
          got the lorem... </p>
    </div>
    <p id="test-para" class="class-1 class-2 class-3">This color stays purple because of precedence! </p>
    <p> This doesn't though..</p>
    <h1> "DON'T FORGET ABOUT ME!!"</h1>
    <ul>
      <li> These list elements are still in position</li>
      <li> tada</li>
    </ul>
  </main>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: He did actually specify no scripts in the comments.

Comment: Not a point. I can hide/ show an element, by using css(#button:hover + #popup {display:[none/block];}    But my problem is, that I  want to hide the whole body content (except #popup) with css.    And I just needed a way to select the whole body content, except the #pop-up

Comment: The problem is in my element selector

Comment: @spikespaz I know and I acknowledged that in my post as well. I still wanted to give the closest solution available.

Comment: @Jishnuraj If you hide everything in body, then nothing will show, because body is the top-level parent node when it comes to what is rendered to the page. 

You are also trying to do logic inside of your css, and that's not what css is designed for. 

Your best bet is to put a popup div just inside body and the rest of your content inside of main right below the pop up. Then use this rule: `#popup:hover ~ * {  visibility: hidden;}` 

This will select all the siblings AFTER the popup div. This also means popup cannot be inside of other content unless you position it there manually.